# How to create a Table with First Column fixed using sap.ui.Table

Tags: sapui5

I am new to Sap ui5 trying to learn different concepts in ui5.
I Want to create a ui5 Table with 5 columns where First Column should be fixed is it possible to make it in sapui5 and my columns are :
[image: This is my table with columns]

```
           <Table  id="table2">
                   <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <m:Text text="S.No"/>
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{serialId}" wrapping="false"  />
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <m:Text text="EmployeeName"  />
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{employeeName}" wrapping="false" />
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <m:Text text="EmployeeId" />
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{employeeId}" wrapping="false" />
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <m:Text text="Department" />
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{department}" wrapping="false" />
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <m:Text text="Status" />
                            <template>
                                <m:Text text="{status}" wrapping="false" />
                            </template>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                </Table>
```

I want to achieve that first column to be fixed (i.e., S.No column should be fixed).How to fix it 
(please let me know if any more information is required), any help is appreciated.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property `fixedColumnCount` of [`sap.ui.table.Table`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23controlProperties)

> Number of columns that are fixed on the left. Only columns which are not fixed can be scrolled horizontally.
>
> **Note**
>
> - Fixed columns need a defined width for the feature to work.
> - The aggregated width of all fixed columns must not exceed the table width. Otherwise the table ignores the value of the property and adapts the behavior in an appropriate way to ensure that the user is still able to scroll horizontally.
>
> Visibility: public

Here is a small snippet of your table with it in effect (I made some other small changes to better show its effect):

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Core"
], Core => Core.attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], (XMLView, JSONModel) => XMLView.create({
  definition: document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML,
  models: new JSONModel({
    data: [{
      serialId: "1",
      employeeName: "John",
      employeeId: 100,
      department: "Accounting",
      status: "Looking good!",
    }],
  }),
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content")))));
```

```html
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.unified"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
    data-sap-ui-async="true"
    data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
  ></script>
  <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns:m="sap.m"
      xmlns="sap.ui.table"
      height="100%">
      <Table id="table2" fixedColumnCount="1" visibleRowCount="3" rows="{/data}">
        <columns>
          <Column width="50px">
            <m:Text text="S.No" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{serialId}" wrapping="false"  />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="EmployeeName" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{employeeName}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="EmployeeId" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{employeeId}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="Department" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{department}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="600px">
            <m:Text text="Status" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{status}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
        </columns>
      </Table>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>
</head>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
</body>
</html>
```

You can also see the sample "[Table Freeze](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TableFreeze)", which demonstrates the various ways to fix columns and rows.

Comment: actually I have a doubt here that will this work when I perform drag and drop since while drag and drop I have to get the whole row which include S.No and it changes too , but I want it to be static.....Should i have to update code for drag and drop too?

Comment: Your question does not mention anything about drag and drop? I have tried enabling fixedColumnCount on the [drag/drop sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.DnD) and it seems to work as I expect it to. If there is a specific problem, maybe you can ask a new question that specifically focusses on the DnD.

Comment: Or did you mean "fixed" as in fixed width? In that case you'd have to set the property `resizable` on the column to `false`.

Comment: i have already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396093/how-to-add-serial-numbers-to-the-table-and-static-during-drag-and-drop-of-a-row..... but didn't get any response so i felt should ask this at first and go step by step...

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7vxgku0t/

Comment: Exactly , but while I was referring to DnD in demo sample from doc's i have seen rank and just want to know how this works when we have to add new row at the end of added row ....here in sample  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.DnD

Comment: Thanks a ton mate,.....But would you please add a delete and edit option for the same such that on delete the serailId should be deleted and updated , hope this makes sense